# Picture of the Week - different aspect ratio and text alignment

Tags: feature-request

We were recently informed that changes to the PotW header made it possible to accept other aspect ratios (which would be GREAT).  Currently the text for the PotW header approximately lines up with right column of the site and looks 'good'.  Taking a narrower picture looks like it would move the text and look 'funky' since it wouldn't align anymore.  Can we float it such that the text will remain where its at with a narrower photo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure whoever is in charge of fixing this knows what they're doing but I thought I would give my suggestions to a possible solution.

**Currently the code is set up like this:**

```
<div id="custom-content"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF4Ee.jpg" alt="Going Northbound On The Bakerloo" />
  <h2> Going Northbound<br/>
    On The Bakerloo
    <p>by <a href="http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697/sean">sean</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/weekly-featured-image-aug-29-11">submit your photo</a></p>
  </h2>
</div>
```

**A possible solution would be to set it up like this:**

```
<div id="custom-content">
  <div id="potw-info">
    <h2> Going Northbound<br/>
      On The Bakerloo
      <p>by <a href="http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697/sean">sean</a></p>
      <p><a href="http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/weekly-featured-image-aug-29-11">submit your photo</a></p>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF4Ee.jpg" alt="Going Northbound On The Bakerloo" />
</div>
```

If you then do a `float:right` on `#potw-info` and `#custom-content img` you would then get something like this.

[image]

This would keep the POTW info as is but align the photo to the right of the main column. That way a new image could be plopped in, as long as it was a consistent 210px high and less than 375px wide, without causing any problems to the layout.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I'll implement this new feature tonight. Should be on live server tomorrow.